# How can I access a private field from a struct in a submodule?

Tags: module, rust, field, private

I want to split my rust module in separate files. So I used a submodule. The problem is I cant access private fields from a struct defined in a submodule. Here is an example:

```
// mod1.rs
mod point;

struct Point1 {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Point1 {
    pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Point1 {
        Point1 { x: x, y: y }
    }
}

pub fn run() {
    let a = Point1::new(1, 2);
    let b = point::Point2::new(3, 4);

    println!("{}, {}", a.x, a.y); // 1, 2
    println!("{}, {}", b.x, b.y); // error
}

// point.rs
pub struct Point2 {
    x: i32,
    y: i32,
}

impl Point2 {
    pub fn new(x: i32, y: i32) -> Point2 {
        Point2 { x: x, y: y }
    }
}
```

How can I split the code in separate files and still access the private members of a struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `pub (super)` to make something only public to its parent module.

```
pub struct Point2 {
    pub (super) x: i32,
    pub (super) y: i32,
}
```

Have a look at the rust docs on [Visibility and Privacy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!